# How to route using ngRoute (with Demo)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope, angularjs-1.2

My code starts from here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<title>Routing</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<a href="#/login">Login</a>
<a href="#/register">Register</a>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
<script src="angular-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.config(function($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider

                  .when("/login", {
                           templateUrl : "login.html"
                           })
                  .when("/register", {
                         templateUrl : "register.html"
                           })                       
                });
</script>
</html>
```

> I cannot route, it is simple touting with html, using simple method , the basic one , i do not know why it doesnt route

Comment: If you want an answer that works with AngularJS 1.6 see [Routing Demo stops working when updated to AngularJS 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51685977/5535245).

Comment: @Amman did you sort out your issue?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, what changes should i do in my code for angular 1.6

Comment: only thing you have to do is use ! <a href="#/!login">Login</a>
<a href="#!/register">Register</a>

Comment: make sure to mark as answer

Comment: @Sajeetharan, not working, dear

Comment: @AmaanImtiyaz check here working demo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685961/routing-demo-stops-working-when-updated-to-angularjs-1-6/51685977#51685977

Comment: did that help you now

Comment: @Sajeetharan, your earlier comment, the one i have flagged helped, i also had CORS error, had to use http protocol, so i developed it in asp.net. asp.net gives a local host server. so it did it  and also i had the CORS plugin on in my browzer. Thanks alot

Comment: it does not have anything to do with the ngRoute. please mark the answer

Comment: flagging is different from marking answer

Comment: @Sajeetharan , yes it doesn't have to do except for the changes i had to put for new angular snippet. I wrote it there for the record for someone having both of problems

Comment: @Sajeetharan, can I please have your phone number, I have a question regarding AngularJs that i cannot ask just by writing. I promise, not be a bother one.

Answer (score 1):

This is with the version 1.2.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"])
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
      template: `<h1>Login</h1>`,
      controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })
    .when('/register', {
      template: `<h1>Register</h1>`,
      controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Login";

});
app.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Register";

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS User Registration and Login Example  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#/login">Login</a>
  <a href="#/register">Register</a>
  <div class="mainContainer" ng-view></div>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you are using Angularjs version 1.6 and above, routes has changed. Look at this **[`Answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685961/routing-demo-stops-working-when-updated-to-angularjs-1-6/51685977?noredirect=1#comment90334048_51685977)**