# Routing Demo stops working when updated to AngularJS 1.6

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, angularjs-1.6

When I updated the code snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51685613/5535245) to use AngularJS 1.6, it stopped working.

The <kbd>Login</kbd> and <kbd>Register</kbd> links no longer change the view.

## The DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"])
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
      template: `<h1>Login</h1>`,
      controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })
    .when('/register', {
      template: `<h1>Register</h1>`,
      controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Login";

});
app.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Register";

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS User Registration and Login Example  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#/login">Login</a>
  <a href="#/register">Register</a>
  <div class="mainContainer" ng-view></div>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular@1.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-route@1.6/angular-route.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: With AngularJS V1.6, the default hash-prefix changed to hashbang. For more information, see [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes in Angular 1.6 changed from **`#/state`** to **`#!/state`**

You should change your ref to:

```
 <a href="#!/login">Login</a>
 <a href="#!/register">Register</a>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"])
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
      template: `<h1>Login</h1>`,
      controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })
    .when('/register', {
      template: `<h1>Register</h1>`,
      controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Login";

});
app.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Register";

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS User Registration and Login Example  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#!/login">Login</a>
  <a href="#!/register">Register</a>
  <div class="mainContainer" ng-view></div>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular@1.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-route@1.6/angular-route.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that's ok accept it when you can. I am a fan of yours on angularjs :)

Comment: i guess you got this question from my previous answer :)

Comment: I thought it was really cruel to give the guy an AngularJS 1.2 answer when he was probably encountering the hashbang issue with V1.6